# remove duplicates withing each observation

Tags: r

I have something like `testDF <- data.frame(v1 = c(  1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5, 5,  7,  7  ,9),v2 = c("a","b","c","d","d","e","e","e","d","d","a","a","a","b") )`

and I need for each obs on v1, to get rid of the duplicates in v2...
 to get something like

`testDF <- data.frame(v1 = c(  1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  7,  9),
                     v2 = c("a","b","c","d","e","e","d","a","a","b") )`

any idea on how can I do that??? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `unique(testDF)` you than get the following output

```
   v1 v2
1   1  a
2   2  b
3   3  c
4   4  d
6   4  e
8   5  e
9   5  d
11  5  a
12  7  a
14  9  b
```